No Display on external monitor
I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on my Asus TUF laptop which has a hybrid graphics card setup amd + nvidia. When I'm running windows I can see display on the external monitor but when I'm running ubuntu I can't see anything. Please help.

The problem is that the HDMI port is connected directly to your GPU. So you need proper configuration and tell the system to use an integrated GPU for the laptop & integrated external monitor.
If you're trying to connect to external monitors using HDMI and you have a hybrid setup like me (AMD Radeon Vega + Nvidia 1650) then these configuration files may help you as it worked for me.
Note: I'm running kali linux(debian based) with kde plasma.

Find my automated script here


sudo (text_editor) /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-amdgpu.conf

Section "OutputClass"
  Identifier "AMDgpu"
  MatchDriver "amdgpu"
  Driver "modesetting"
EndSection


sudo (text_editor) /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia-drm-outputclass.conf

Section "OutputClass"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    MatchDriver "nvidia-drm"
    Driver "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
    ModulePath "/usr/lib/nvidia/xorg"
    ModulePath "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    Option "PrimaryGPU" "Yes"
EndSection


Make sure no other config files named interfere 10-nvidia-drm-outputclass.conf & 10-amdgpu.conf (in /etc/X11 or /usr/share/X11).


Finally


Display managers (choose yours):
LightDM

create /etc/lightdm/display_setup.sh

#!/bin/sh
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource modesetting NVIDIA-0
xrandr --auto


Make the script executable:

chmod +x /etc/lightdm/display_setup.sh

Now configure lightdm to run the script by editing the [Seat:*] section in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf :
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
[Seat:*] display-setup-script=/etc/lightdm/display_setup.sh

Now reboot and your display manager should start.
If your display dpi is not correct add the following line (applies also to the other display managers):
xrandr --dpi 96

SDDM
/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource modesetting NVIDIA-0; xrandr --auto

GDM
/usr/share/gdm/greeter/autostart/optimus.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/optimus.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Optimus
Exec=sh -c "xrandr --setprovideroutputsource modesetting NVIDIA-0; xrandr --auto"
NoDisplay=true
X-GNOME-Autostart-Phase=DisplayServer

Make sure that GDM use X as default backend.

Enable prime synchronisation

edit or create: /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia.conf:
add:
options nvidia-drm modeset=1


Blacklist nouveau:

sudo bash -c "echo blacklist nouveau > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf"
sudo bash -c "echo options nouveau modeset=0 >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf"


Update initramfs:

sudo update-initramfs -u -k all


Reboot.

This was the original ticket I opened and the nvidia support super actively helped me thanks to them I can work on my new monitor. https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/having-problem-while-using-external-monitor-on-parrot-os/199476/18



Wow thank you so much it worked for me. Will it work on other distros other than ubuntu ?
Can we use this for intel + other GPU combination ?

I'm not 100% sure but I have tested it on kali, parrot OS, Debian & manjaro  & so far all of them worked. Please contact your laptop provider or graphics card provider

Thank you so much
